# Adding options which are not present in Metadata in a Option Set in Dynamics-365

Tags: dynamics-crm, option-set

I have created an option set field in an entity in CRM that has 3 options.

Now I want to add another option based on some conditions dynamically(maybe when the page loads).

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you cannot create new Option set Value/Option on the fly which is not available in Database/Metadata.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure it can save into the database and be available in other places like views.

You should create an option set with every possible value.

Then use JavaScript to hide the options you don't want.

[`removeOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/controls/removeoption)

```
formContext.getControl("your_control").removeOption(1);
```

Comment: I know that. But my question was whether is it possible to add options dynamically in the option set that are not present in metadata?

Comment: I think you could use `addOption` to show it on screen, but I'm not sure it will save into the database.